# Heatmap with leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet

I get geojson from Austin Government with polygons of districts and names.

```
gjson_austin <- geojson_read('Neighborhood Planning Areas.geojson', 
method = "local", what = "sp")
gjson_austin@proj4string<-CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
gjson_austin<-as(gjson_austin, 'SpatialPolygons')
place_name_austin = fread("ci6h-vmgm.csv")
```

After that, i make DF:

```
austin_frame <- gjson_austin%>%fortify()
austin_frame$id <- as.numeric(austin_frame$id)
objects_austin <- left_join(austin_frame, place_name_austin%>%select(FID, PLANNING_A), by = c("id"="FID"))
```

Now i have a dataframe:

```
'data.frame':   10268 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ long      : num  -97.7 -97.7 -97.7 -97.7 -97.7 ...
 $ lat       : num  30.3 30.3 30.3 30.3 30.3 ...
 $ order     : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ hole      : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ piece     : Factor w/ 16 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ id        : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ group     : Factor w/ 126 levels "0.1","1.1","2.1",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ PLANNING_A: chr  "CHESTNUT" "CHESTNUT" "CHESTNUT" "CHESTNUT" ...
```

Polygons grouped by id. Every polygon has a name in PLANNING_A column.

I want to draw this polygons with leaflet.

```
leaflet() %>% addTiles()%>%
addPolygons(data = objects_austin, lng = ~long, lat = ~lat)
```

But i get not what i need.
[image: polygons do not connect correctly]

I can draw polygons if I use

```
leaflet() %>% addTiles()%>%
addPolygons(data=gjson_austin)
```

but I need values from json for my calculations.
Help me please with this problem.

After that I calculate any special values grouped by polygons. I want draw correct polygons by this values like a heatmap.